# How to use the PASCAL VOC dataset in the xml format to build the model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a PASCAL VOC dataset. I would like to use it to build a deep learning model in tensorflow. I think that I need to convert it into the TFRecord file format to build the model but I am unsure that my thought is correct. If it is, what is the code convert the  PASCAL VOC into the TFRecord file format. If it is not, do you have suggestions to load this PASCAL VOC dataset to build a model in tensorflow. This is my PASCAL VOC data set.

```
<annotation>
  <filename>000000000.jpg</filename>
  <source>
    <annotation>ArcGIS Pro 2.1</annotation>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>256</width>
    <height>256</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <object>
    <name>0</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>209.62</xmin>
        <ymin>3.86</ymin>
        <xmax>256.00</xmax>
        <ymax>70.93</ymax>
    </bndbox>
 </object>
 <object>
    <name>0</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>120.92</xmin>
        <ymin>126.09</ymin>
        <xmax>200.23</xmax>
        <ymax>209.97</ymax>
    </bndbox>
 </object>
 <object>
    <name>0</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>237.72</xmin>
        <ymin>136.02</ymin>
        <xmax>256.00</xmax>
        <ymax>214.18</ymax>
    </bndbox>
 </object>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Tensorflow Object Detection API provides a [tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md) for it, you can run the following command:

```
python object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py \
    --label_map_path=<path/to/label/map.pbtxt> \
    --data_dir=<path/to/data/dir> --year=<year_directory_name> --set=<train|test|val> \
    --output_path=pascal_<train|test|val>.record
```

This expects a tree of the form

```
data_dir
|- year_dir
   |- Annotations
      |- *.xml
   |- ImageSets
      |- Layout
        |- test.txt
        |- train.txt
        |- val.txt
        |- trainval.txt
      |- Main
        |- *.txt
   |- JPEGImages
      |- *.jpg
```

For instance, with the usual PASCAL dataset, the result would be :

```
python object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py \
    --label_map_path=object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt \
    --data_dir=VOCdevkit --year=VOC2012 --set=val \
    --output_path=pascal_val.record
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the individual files & folders mean? I can't find any explaination online. Edit: As always, one minute after asking I find something ;) https://programmer.help/blogs/tenor-flow-2.0-note-10-pascal-voc-data-set-introduction.html

Comment: Ok now I get it thanks. But from a coding automation, I wonder why they didn't read the xml itself to get the files informations? Like the xml files would be the one ready, and each file they reference to would be that file, and it would matter the file format also. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

`VOC2007` is available in the latest `tensorflow-datasets==1.0.2` version, (which is not available on `pip` yet).

To install it run this in a terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets
cd datasets
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Usage example (plot in `Jupyter`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
%matplotlib inline

OUTLINE = (0, 255, 0)

builder = tfds.builder('voc2007')
builder.download_and_prepare()
datasets = builder.as_dataset()
train_data, test_data = datasets['train'], datasets['test']
iterator = train_data.repeat(1).batch(1).make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(1):
        batch = sess.run(next_batch)
        image = batch['image']
        bboxes = batch['objects']['bbox']
        bboxes, image = np.squeeze(bboxes), np.squeeze(image)
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        try:
            if (isinstance(bboxes[0], np.float32)
                or isinstance(bboxes[0], np.float64)):
                bboxes = [bboxes]

            for bbox in bboxes:
                ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = bbox
                xmin *= width
                xmax *= width
                ymin *= height
                ymax *= height
                c1 = (xmin, ymin)
                c2 = (xmax, ymin)
                c3 = (xmax, ymax)
                c4 = (xmin, ymax)
                draw.line([c1, c2, c3, c4, c1],
                          fill=OUTLINE,
                          width=3)
            asnumpy = np.array(pil_image)
            figure = plt.figure(figsize=tuple(x/50 for x in image.shape[:2]))
            plt.imshow(asnumpy)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

[image]